# Open links in new tab chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I've created a simple chrome app that has  links, at the moment none of the links are working, even using `target="_blank"` wouldn't work so I thought I was stuck until I found [openTab](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser#method-openTab). Though, I'm new to javascript never mind Chrome Apps so I'm don't know how to actually implement this into my code so that I can open links in new tabs.

I have tried this:

```
$(".logo").click(function(){
     chrome.browser.openTab({ url: "http://www.google.com/" }, callback);
});
```

Which gives me this error when I click on logo:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openTab' of undefined
at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (script.js:126)
at HTMLImageElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
at HTMLImageElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
```

My Manifest:

```
{
"name": "example",
"description": "example",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"app": {
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js", "script.js"]
}
},
"permissions": ["browser"],
"icons": {
"128": "logo.png"
}
}
```

Comment: Which Chrome Version do you use ?

Comment: Version 56.0.2924.87

Comment: Do you think i need to specify that im using jquery under "scripts"?

Comment: No, the jqeury is not the error. The error says, that `chrome.browser is undefined`, consequently i asked for the chrome version.

Comment: Is this actually a Chrome App, or a Chrome extension? You have tagged it as both. It should only have 1 of those tags. Please [edit] the question to remove the one this is *not*. The error you are getting could be explained by this being an extension, not an app.

Comment: Have done. Am i using the openTab code in the correct way? Seems logical to me but there is no documentation that explains exactly how i use it.

Answer (score 0):

If your code for the jquery call is in scripts.js, I recommend it being placed in the HTML itself, right before the body closing tag, instead of as a background script.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```